# Difference between Java EE 7 and Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What are the main differences between Java EE 7 and Java EE 6 ?

If you would have to explain to another fellow developer the main differences
how would you do that ?

As far as the question goes, I was really interested not in the new added technologies, but for the already present ones.

A quick overview would be most than enough for what I'm asking.

To add a further question I'd love to know what major improvements have been added to 
JAX-WS, JAX-RS and JSF, Is still a Hero task to develop services with Java EE and not rely
on external frameworks as Spring for example ?

Comment: great link, thanks. Under "Additional Resources" you might find some similar stuff here: https://glassfish.java.net/documentation.html

Comment: This contains helpful links: http://javaee7.zeef.com

Comment: Java EE 7 adds 4 new specs:

* Java API for WebSocket 1.0
* Java API for JSON Processing
* Batch Processing for the Java Platform 1.0
* Concurrency Utilities for the Java EE Platform

3 specs have gone through major update:

* JAX-RS 1.1 -> JAX-RS 2.0
* JMS 1.1 -> JMS 2.0
* EL 3.0 (new standalone spec)

Several other improvements:

* Alignment of Managed Beans across the platform
* Default enablement of CDI
* javax.persistence.schema-generation.* properties in JPA
* Faces Flow, Resource Library Contract, Pass-through attributes in JSF 2.2
* Security improvements in Servlet
* Many others

Comment: Just to add. http://www.iseebug.com/category/java/

Answer (score 24):

When Java EE 7 was released I read a really good overview on heise.de. Here is the English version of it:

http://www.h-online.com/developer/features/Java-EE-7-at-a-glance-1889207.html

I think this a really good detailed explanation with already some examples to understand what exactly changed.

Some of the main changes in Java EE 7:

- Next Version of Webservices
- Support for JSON
- Improved Bean-Validation
- New Version of the Java Message Services (JMS)
- Glassfish 4

Comment: Answers like these are always better when they give a brief synopsis of the linked material.

Comment: Please edit your answer, so it contains something more than link. Maybe revelant excerpts from linked articles?

Comment: I alread wrote that it contains the changes of ee7 and already some examples, but i now added some of the main changes in Java EE 7

Comment: jsf 2.2 is pretty significant