# Are there new data structures in Java 7 vs. Java 6?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a book on Data Structures from 2010, Data Structures: [Abstraction and Design Using Java, Second Edition.](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001607.html)

It uses Java 6.

Are there significant differences in Data Structures between Java 6 and 7?  On a side question, what about Java 8?

I'd like to use this book if I can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515116/difference-between-java-ee-7-and-java-ee-6

Comment: @merlin2001 That link is not at all relevant.  It talks about JEE7 vs JEE6.  OP is interested in JSE7 vs JSE6.

Comment: As I don't have a complete answer, I'd just like to mention that for `Comparable` keys `HashMaps` now have `O(lg n)` worst-case performance

Comment: This question seems to be nonsense. Data structures are data structures and language is language. Are you asking whether some syntactic sugar in Java 8 fundamentally changes the way a red black tree works? Or whether in introduction of diamond syntax somehow affects a linked list?

Comment: @BoristheSpider OP might be asking if/how the default implementations differ between releases

Comment: It's worth noting that Java is 99.9% backwards compatible. So anything that works in java 6 should work in 7 and 8 as well as any future versions. There just might be easier ways to achieve the same thing in later versions. That said; I'm not sure I'd want to give up diamond inference and I'm coming around to lambdas

Comment: Also; java 8 streams don't effect collections themselves but give us a very different way to interact with them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are changes.  No, it is not relevant to whether you use that book.

The book is designed to teach you how a range of basic data structures and algorithms work at a fundamental level so that you understand how they work and what their computational properties are.  While they cover a number of Java data structure classes and interfaces in the process, this is secondary.  It is not the aim of the book to be a detailed tutorial on Java's data structure APIs.

In this light, the changes from Java 6 to Java 7 are largely beyond the scope of the book:

- The forkjoin framework is an alternative to classical threads ... which was already out of scope.
- The changes to the sort algorithms are an implementation detail.  The new timsort algorithm is an amalgam of existing algorithms and techniques that is not instructive from a teaching perspective.
- There have been no significant changes to the core APIs between Java 6 and Java 7 that would render what is in the book out-of-date.

So, I'd advise you to use the book ... especially if you already have a copy.

(But if the real issue here is that your teachers recommend a different textbook, you should compare the two books rather than asking a Question like this.  This Question is moot if their reasons for recommending another one are not to do with Java 6 versus Java 7.)

---

If there is a new eddition of the book based on Java 8 that deals with lambdas and streams, *that* could be a worthwhile buy.  Meanwhile, this one is just fine for either Java 6 or Java 7.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not in school though.  All personal study.  I like to teach myself all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a page listing [changes between Java 6 and Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html).

Based on that page and the table of contents of your book, I wouldn't say there are any significant "data structures" changes.

The `ForkJoinPool` qualify, but it would probably be considered more 'advanced' than the topics in the book.  There's also a bug fix to  `TreeMap` that detects errors you could previously get away with, but that's pretty minor anyway and correct code shouldn't change as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The only major difference, which I'm aware about, between Java 6 and Java 7 is that the other sorting algorithm is used by default for non primitive objects.

- Before Java 7 - [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- After Java 7 - [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

This is when you call *java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[] array)* or *java.util.Collections.sort(...)* because collections are copied to an array before sorting.
Please bear in mind that for primitives Java still uses dual-pivot quicksort and the old behavior in Java 7 can be achieved with *"java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort"* system property.